# MultipleLookupField validation errors when publishing a page

Tags: 2010, publishing-site

Whenever I try to publish a page that contains a MultipleLookupField I get the error

> You must fill out all required properties before completing this action.

My setup is very simple

- I am using an OOB Publishing Site
- Custom site column MyCustomColumn that is a lookup on a list and allows multiple values
- Custom content type MyCustomContentType based on Page that includes the MyCustomColumn and is required
- Custom page layout MyCustomPageLayout that uses MyCustomContentType

I create a page that uses MyCustomPageLayout and MyCustomContentType and put it in edit mode.  In the MultipleLookupField for MyCustomColumn I choose a value and click Add.  When I click Publish I get the error.  Why is this happening?  Any ideas to help diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened a support ticket with Microsoft regarding this issue and they have verified this is a bug that was introduced in Service Pack 1.  The product group is working to find a solution to this problem.